# LaTeX - how to change intra-document link format?

Tags: latex

I love LaTeX but can't figure out how to change the red box around linked items (TOC to document detail, glossary entries used within the document) to the standard blue underline that you see most often.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Since LaTeX _is_ computer software, this question is technically on-topic for Super User. However, there is [a Stack Exchange site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to LaTeX questions, where you might get a better answer. If you would like, a moderator can migrate your question there for you; just flag your question for moderator attention using the flag link and mention you'd like it migrated there.

Answer (score 2):

This can be controlled by the `linkbordercolor` [option for Hyperlinks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization). For example:

```
\hypersetup{
    linkbordercolor={0 0 1}    % uses format {red green blue},
                               % where each value is between 0 and 1
}
```

should set the default border colour to blue.

Answer (score 1):

(Might be a candidate for migration to [the TeX/LaTeX site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).)

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/823/remove-ugly-borders-around-clickable-crossreferences-and-hyperlinks/824#824) is part of the way there, but there's a comment below (untested by me) that says

```
\ifpdf\usepackage[pdftex,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1},hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}\fi
```

should work. If you're working exclusively with PDFs, you can drop the `\ifpdf`, `pdftex`, and `\fi`. See also [Wikibooks' hyperref customization section](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization).